# Editing Theme and Moving Servers

Tags: themes, import, server, export

Ok, So I have a wordpress installed on a test server. I just edited the default theme to get my desired result. My question is could I just install a new version of wordpress on another server and copy/paste my theme - simple as that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't added a bunch of content and widgets on the local server, yes, it can be as easy as that.

If you want to move *everything* - all your settings and content and such - you can follow these instructions: http://www.billerickson.net/how-to-move-your-wordpress-website/

G'luck!

Comment: Bad link! Bad! No cookie! :) Plain text replacement on database potentially breaks serialized data!

Comment: I've never considered that and now it's come up three times this morning! Funny. @Rarst would you recommend a tool like this? http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Absolutely! Interconnect/it folks have been offering that tool for a long time. Myself I use BackupBuddy a lot for migrations lately, but that one is paid.

Comment: Great, I've got it bookmarked. My next WordPress move will be fully and gloriously serialized-data-friendly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to move is theme, than it is indeed straight copy/paste.

But I want to note that default theme gets updated and overwritten with WP updates, as well as by its own separate updates. If you want to tweak it you should create [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for it and implement tweaks in it.

If you want to move content as well things get a little more complicated. In basic case you can use native export/import feature, for more complex cases there are plugins around for moving installation around, adjusting URL changes and such.

Comment: Not a problem, I don't update wordpress for this reason exactly!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee ouch... :) You should really, really, **really** update WordPress. Security and such. Getting hacked sucks. And so on.